# Smooth animation start

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I've got an animation that just moves from top to the bottom.

0 - top
25 - middle
50 - bottom
75 - middle
100 - top

I've made it endless using javascript but every time it stops and starts again it blinks (disappears and appears for 1 second).

Is there a way to make this action smooth without blinking at start?

Comment: Help people help you by giving them a minimal example to reproduce the issue. Sounds like something that should be done in just css anyway.

Comment: @ChrisW. I wish I could but the problem is I'm working with images on localhost and javascript works with a specified path. Tried to put in into a jsfiddle but it didn't work though :(

Comment: You can just use other images. We don't need an exact replica of what you're doing, we just need a minimal working example to show what's going wrong. You could even just use a `div` with a `background-color` instead of an image

Comment: Can you show us your code? The animation in css would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code it's difficult to know, but I'd imagine it may have something to do with the way you've set up your @keyframes. For an infinite looping animation with no glitch, try something like this:

**HTML:**

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation: mymove 2s infinite; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation: mymove 2s infinite;
}
```

**CSS:**

```
/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    0%   {top: 0px;}
    50%  {top: 100px;}
    100% {top: 0px;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes mymove {
    0%   {top: 0px;}
    50%  {top: 100px;}
    100% {top: 0px;}
}
```

Hope this helps